# How do i fix reshaping my dataset for cross validation?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

```
x_train:(153347,53)
x_test:(29039,52)
y:(153347,)
```

I am working with sklearn. To cross validate and reshape my dataset i did:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(
x, y, test_size=0.3)

x_train = np.pad(x, [(0,0)], mode='constant')
x_test = np.pad(x, [(0,0)], mode='constant')
y = np.pad(y, [(0,0)], mode='constant')
x_train = np.arange(8127391).reshape((-1,1))
c = x.T
np.all(x_train == c)
x_test = np.arange(1510028).reshape((-1,1))
c2 = x.T
np.all(x_test == c2)
y = np.arange(153347).reshape((-1,1))
c3 = x.T
np.all(y == c3)
```

My error message is:ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [ 2 153347]

I am not sure i need to pad my dataset in this case and the reshape is not working. Any ideas on how i can fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you should mention that you use sklearn and describe more what you're doing. Otherwise, chances are high that it is simply ignored.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip.

Comment: where is this message originating from? It seems that you simply passed a transposed `y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the little we see here one, I believe the call to `cross_validation.train_test_split` dumps because the the length of the two vectors does not coincide. So for every X (the data tuple we you observe) you need a Y (the data-point that is observed as a result).

At least this leads to the error shown above.

You should definitely improve on the formulation of the problem. Very much so.

regards, fricke

Comment: I see what you are saying, the problem is calling y_test since it does not exist in the dataframe. Thanks!

Comment: if this solves the problem could you accept the solution, thanks

Comment: Ok one last thing if you can help. Do i need to merge separate files of train and test to perform a cross validation? I have the csv as a train csv and a test csv. Can i just merge them into one and program based on separating my dataset as x and y instead?

Comment: Yes, at least this is a way to achieve a cross validation. But Sklearn offers you a very convenient method of doing it by passing the entire learning and test-set to the function 'cross_val_score'. This function then splits entire set into a series of disjoint learning and test sets and does an average on the score.